# Control flow returns from model without landing into controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core project. I am using a view model to bind incoming data from request.

In view model I'm doing a data annotation `[Required]` validation. If the data is empty for that particular field, the execution returns from there without passing to a controller.

I need the execution to go to controller to modify the response with my custom messages along with model-state errors.

My model looks like

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = ErrorConstants.required)]
[StringLength(5, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = ErrorConstants.invalid)]
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = ErrorConstants.incorrectInputFormat)]
public string ZipCode { get; set; }
```

My controller action method sample. Please guide.

```
if (viewModel == null)
{
    _dictionary = _apiResponseService.SetResponse("false", ErrorConstants.nullOrIncorrect);
    return Ok(_dictionary);
}
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return Ok(_apiResponseService.SetResponse("false", ErrorConstants.invalidJson, ModelState.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key.Replace("viewModel.", ""),
      kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Select(error =>
      {
          if (error.Exception == null)
          {
              return error.ErrorMessage;
          }
          else
          {
              return string.Format(ErrorConstants.required, kvp.Key.Split('.').Last());
          }
      }).FirstOrDefault())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the workaround for this. In controller, comment out [ApiController] attribute and the work is done.

Answer (score 0):

The new `[ApiController]` attribute has a feature where

> validation errors automatically trigger an HTTP 400 response.

Most likely the model state is invalid. That is the reason why it is not hitting your action.

> The default behavior is disabled when the
>   `SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter` property is set to `true`. Add the
>   following code in *Startup.ConfigureServices* after
>   `services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);`:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SuppressConsumesConstraintForFormFileParameters = true;
    options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
    options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true; //<-- THIS HERE
});
```

So instead of removing the `[ApiController]` attribute altogether, keep it and disable that default behavior so that the controller can keep what ever advantages it provided and still get to check model state in the action.

Reference [Build web APIs with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1)